# Pass date as an argument in method to determine if today's date is Monday and decrease the date by 3

Tags: python, pandas

I want to determine if a day on the date is Monday and then print the date as of Friday's date i.e. Monday-3. I am trying this following code.

```
def giveDate(date):
    if datetime.today().weekday()==0:
        print("Monday")
        date=date-3
        print(date)
giveDate("2022-08-15")
```

I am getting the following error line 39, in giveDate
if datetime.today().weekday()==0:
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'

Comment: You're missing a `date` - `datetime.date.today().weekday()`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def giveDate(date: str) -> None:
    # Convert given date string to datetime
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if datetime.now().weekday() == 0:
        print("Monday")
        # Subtract 3 days and return date formatted similarly to input
        date = (date - timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print(date)
```

```py
giveDate("2022-08-15")

# OUT
# Monday
# 2022-08-12
```